# Creating a full path to sub-directory on a server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, filepath, subdirectory

I am currently working on a Rails application and recently received a request to add the ability to go to a sub-directory on the server at work. 
i.e. each `LINK` will take you to `smb://my/server/directory/sub-directory`

The problem: say that `directory` is the large directory containing all the sub directories. Here are some examples to illustrate what I mean.

I have 3 car records. The sub directory is made up of a concatenation of 2 attributes, the first 3 digits of carA.number (something like `carA.number.split('-')[0]`, cause it's formatted ###-####-#) a hyphen, and the description of the car (something like `carA.description_of_car`). The full path would be something like `smb://my/server/directory/carA.number.split('-')[0] - carA.description_of_car`

How can I ensure I point my link to the right sub directory if I don't know it's path to be "guaranteed" each time? Since the description attribute can be pretty much anything, and the subdirectory description is the same, it just might have extra spaces or something. As an example, carA's description might be "RED, CAR" but the sub-directory is "RED CAR" so it's missing a comma, then a direct link would break since the paths do not match.

So far what I have tried is this.

```
    base_url = "smb://my/server/directory/"
    car_prefix = @car.number.split('-')[0]
    car_suffix = "-" + @car.description_of_car.split(' ')[0]

    @full_url = base_url + part_prefix + part_suffix
```

obviously, not correct. what I'd like to do, is add a wildcard to the url, so that it finds a sub-folder with at least the first 3 numbers correct (cause those will always be in the right format, ###-####)

edit: something like this: @full_url = "smb://my/server/directory/123-*" would match the sub folder for car number `123-RED CAR`

Cheers.

Comment: Does your rails app run on the same host where the directories exist?

Comment: Yes it does, however the database is being copied from a SQL-Server db to a local postgreSQL db so that it plays nicely with Rails. The app is run on the same host as the directory... i believe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's kind of convoluted, but it sounds like you need help matching a directory name and you don't have clearly defined rules for what that directory name should be.

If so, I can think of a few options:

1. Store the directory name in a table beforehand and reference that.
2. Change the directory naming convention into something more sane.
3. Find the rules used to create the directory name in the first place
   and re-use that code.
4. Recreate the rules as assumptions, check to see if the directory
   exists, if not try other assumptions until one does exist.

In terms specifically of finding the existing directory checkout [Dir.glob](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob). It takes a file globbing param you could split on whitespace, strip non-alphanumeric characters and join with splats(*).

e.g., pseudocode: `dir_name.gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").split(/\s/).join("*")`

Comment: would it be reasonable to get to the directory, and then retrieve each of it's sub directories? I should have been more clear, I can get to the root, but I can't go deeper since the naming conventions are all bs'd and human error is plaguing this db.